# How can I improve performance?

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO TableTemp (......)
SELECT .....
FROM ViewTable cs
WHERE NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT *

    FROM TableA s

    WHERE s.location_locCode = cs.store
    AND s.stockUnit_country = cs.country
    AND s.stockUnit_upcCode = cs.upc
)
and EXISTS (

    SELECT *

    FROM TableB l

    WHERE cs.store = l.locCode
    AND cs.country=l.country
);
```

The above sql statement is too slow.

How can I improve performance?

A TableView is a view, a view that has data remotely from another server.

index : 
[TableA]
  country, skuItem
  country, skuCode
  country, upcCode
[TableB]
  locCode, country
  locCode

Comment: We really would need far more information, such as schema including indexes, the actual query along with the query plan.

Comment: Start by running EXPLAIN PLAN and look for table scans.  Make sure there are indexes on the columns in WHERE clauses.  You probably can't, because this is at least O(n) and probably O(n^2).

Comment: Try breaking the query into two parts, Insert first part data into Temporary table and then use Temporary data in second part. Hit and Try...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using and what are the credentials being used to access the remote table? This will affect if the local session can access the remote statistics. Pre SQL2012SP1 you needed more than just READ permissions to view remote statistics.

Comment: You also need to know how many records are involved in each of your tables. Execution plan could help you chose where to use indexes: on the country column could be a first guess

Comment: The problem is most likely the link to the remote server. Your SQL instance is probably retrieving all the view's content to join with your local tables instead of doing the join remotely. The query execution plan will tell you if this is the case or not.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is can help, 
but i think using join is faster than using subquery and we can change your query to be like this

```
SELECT .....
FROM ViewTable cs left join tableA s on (s.location_locCode = cs.store AND s.stockUnit_country = cs.country AND s.stockUnit_upcCode = cs.upc)
    left join TableB l on (cs.store = l.locCode AND cs.country=l.country)
where s.id is null and l.id is not null
```

and dont forget to use proper index to speed up the process ...

hope this can help ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a various way to improve the performance of the query (Generic solution)

- Re-write your query in optimize the way
- create an index on the required column
- Check query plan and if require do partition

I am sharing query option for you by which you can improve the performance up to an extent although to understand the performance you need to cross check each approach

```
Apporach 1:- 
INSERT INTO TableTemp (......)
SELECT .....
FROM ViewTable cs

WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP (1) 'x'
                   FROM TableA s
                   WHERE s.location_locCode = cs.store
                   AND s.stockUnit_country = cs.country
                   AND s.stockUnit_upcCode = cs.upc )
and EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'x'
           FROM TableB l
           WHERE cs.store = l.locCode
           AND cs.country=l.country);

------------------------------------------------------------
Approach #2 
--------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT .....
FROM ViewTable cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA s ON s.location_locCode = cs.store
                   AND s.stockUnit_country = cs.country
                   AND s.stockUnit_upcCode = cs.upc
CROSS APPLY   ( SELECT TOP 1 l.id
                FROM TableB l
                WHERE cs.store = l.locCode
                AND cs.country=l.country) tmp 
WHERE s.Id IS NULL
```

---

```
Approach #3 
--------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT .....
FROM ViewTable cs
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 Id 
              FROM tableA s 
              WHERE s.location_locCode = cs.store
                   AND s.stockUnit_country = cs.country
                   AND s.stockUnit_upcCode = cs.upc) tmp2 
CROSS APPLY   ( SELECT TOP 1 l.id
                FROM TableB l
                WHERE cs.store = l.locCode
                AND cs.country=l.country) tmp 
WHERE tmp2.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to share the plan then here's where your key problem might be.

SQL might perform a Nested Loop to access [ViewTable], this is probably not ideal, because it might actually end up performing multiple full scans of the embedded remote tables (if it has no visibility of remote statistics).

If you can't get access to the remote statistics then it may be less costly to temporarily import full copies of the columns you need in the remote tables. Then write a local query to work with the temporary tables.

After that it's the usual Indexing and LEFT JOIN where NOT NULL.